# Android Launch Activity On Resume

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application, I have 5 Activities. `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`. Activities `B`,`C`,`D`,`E` extend Activity `A` which extends AppCompat. When the application starts from Android Studio, Activity `A` launches Activity `B`. From Activity `B`, the user can decide which activity to load either `C`, `D`, or `E`. My code works fine until the user exits the application and decides to launch it again. The application shows Activity `A` and does not take the user to Activity `B`. I want the user to see Activity `B`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your **Intent process for Activity B** and also the **manifest declaration for the same Activity**?

Comment: I am confused as to why you are mentioned onResume() here.. since in your question you state "User EXITS" the application an re launches it. This means Activity B got destroyed. Which means on re-launch, Activity A‘s onCreate() will be called. Without the code I cannot say what is going wrong, but if you handle Intent in onCreate() of Activity A, then it SHOULD work.

Comment: Unless you meant actually "When App goes into background and is being brought back to foreground.." then onResume() will indeed be triggered, but should be from Activity B and not A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should define Activity B as your launcher in the Manifest, I am assuming Activity A was defined as the launcher by a template/default.

```
<activity name="{Activity B's name}">     
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity B will be the 'root' of your application, at the moment Activity B is added on-top of Activity A in the stack.

If Activity A is also doing a bunch of bootstrapping, another approach will be needed but more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the onResume() method to show activity B?

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.id.layout_B);
}
```

Comment: If his question is correctly written, then Activity B gets destroyed and so does the Activity A => "User EXITS the App". It does not go in background, where onPause() and later onResume() would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain application state after your app closes, you may want to use `SharedPreferences`:

```
final String CURR_ACTIVITY_KEY = "curr_activity";
int currentActivityKey = 1;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
prefs.edit().putInt(CURR_ACTIVITY_KEY, currentActivityKey).commit();
```